# Xor Encryption/Decryption Python 2.7.5

Tags: python, python-2.7, encryption, xor

I know there is a built in xor operator that can be imported in Python. I'm trying to execute the xor encryption/decryption. So far I have:

```
def xor_attmpt():
    message = raw_input("Enter message to be ciphered: ")
    cipher = []
    for i in message:
        cipher.append(bin(ord(i))[2::])#add the conversion of the letters/characters
#in your message from ascii to binary withoout the 0b in the front to your ciphered message list
    cipher = "".join(cipher) 
    privvyKey = raw_input("Enter the private key: ")
    keydecrypt = []
    for j in privvyKey:
        keydecrypt.append(bin(ord(j))[2::]) #same
    keydecrypt = "".join(keydecrypt )#same

    print "key is '{0}'" .format(keydecrypt) #substitute values in string
    print "encrypted text is '{0}'" .format(cipher)
    from operator import xor
    for letter in message:
        print xor(bool(cipher), bool(keydecrypt))
```

This:

```
>  for letter in message:
    print xor(bool(cipher), bool(keydecrypt))
```

is where my python starts to go wrong.

```
The ouput looks like this
    Enter message to be ciphered: hello
Enter the private key: \@154>
key is '10111001000000110001110101110100111110'
encrypted text is '11010001100101110110011011001101111'
False
False
False
False
False
```

What I'm messing up on is trying to get these two binary(key and encrypted) to be compared and give true(1) or false(being 0). The xor should then give me a resulting 1 and 0 binary list from comparing the two. Any input?

Comment: You should be testing the code in the interpreter *as you write it*. Currently it seems you work like this: write a huge chunk of code, hope it works. Normally this is bad strategy. You should write small pieces, test them in the interpreter, assemble larger structures. Step-by-step you will be able to test and verify the validity of your code instead of writing something big and hoping it will work.

Comment: Syon-my question was on hold so I did duplicate.

Comment: The solution to an on-hold question is to fix it and wait till the hold is removed. Alternatively, delete the old question and post a new (fixed) one.

Comment: thanx. :D I'm new to all this. I'll remember to do that.

Answer (score 4):

The `bool()` constructor converts any value into either `True` or `False`. Since you are passing it a non-empty string in each case `bool(cipher)` and `bool(keydecrypt)` each just convert to `True` and `xor(True,True)` is `False.

Forget about converting to a string of 0 and 1, all you actually need to do is xor the character codes you get from calling `ord()` and then convert back to a character with `chr()`. also, you don't need to import a function, Python has a perfectly functional xor operator `^`.

Something like this ought to work:

```
import itertools
print(''.join(chr(ord(k)^ord(c)) for c,k in zip(cipher,itertools.cycle(keydecrypt))))
```

Comment: thank you. One question. What is the function of zip()?

Comment: It combines corresponding elements from multiple sequences. e.g. `list(zip("abc", "def"))` gives `[('a', 'd'), ('b', 'e'), ('c', 'f')]` so in my example it would set `c` and `k` to the first character of each string, then the second character, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You made some mistakes:

1. `cipher` and `keydecrypt` are not binary, they are strings containing 0 and 1 characters.
2. There is no need to import `xor` function, you already have the xor operator `^`
3. Converting a string to boolean in python will get you False if string == '' and True in every other case, which  is not what you want.
4. I didn't understand what the last `for` is supposed to do.

Here is an example about how you could improve you code:

```
import itertools
import binascii

encrypted = ''
for m, k in itertools.izip(message, itertools.cycle(key)):
    encrypted += chr(ord(m) ^ ord(k))

print binascii.hexlify(encrypted)
```

This would work also if `key` is smaller than `message`.

Comment: +1 for using `itertools.cycle` on the key. I should have remembered to include that in my answer (so I edited mine to include it).